# FlaskBootstrapSecurity - basic clone does not work

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am tring to startup a basic FlaskBootstrapSecurity app dev environment (Ubuntu server).

1. cloned git
2. did pip install requirements
3. I edited config.py with just user ID's (see below)
4. Modified manage.py to start server with host='0.0.0.0'.

Then I do `python manage.py runserver` and it says Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ [in VENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py:87]

On browser (laptop) when I try SERVER_NAME:5000 I get a 404.

I've figured out it is in the log function (line 87).  But stuck...

Any help is appreciated.

I cloned into a $HOME/dev dir such that...

```
 $HOME/dev/FlashBootstrapSecurity/flask_application
```

I want to use the Blueprint plugin and security features... but finding it hard to setup ... more than 3 days and now I have reverted to get the basic clone working... no luck.

```
myid = 'myid@gmail.com'
mypw = '***'

# CUSTOMIZED FOR myapp - these are inserted into the Config object

myApp_SYS_ADMINS = myid
myApp_MAIL_USERNAME = myid
myApp_MAIL_PASSWORD = mypw
myApp_SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER = 'Security < '+myid+' >'

### DO NOT TOUCH BELOW

class Config(object):
    def __init__(self):
```

Comment: I decided to take a different tact, ie. build up FlaskBootstrapSecurity from the parts... so I merged into a new tree: 
TOP/flask-security
TOP/flask-script
TOP/templates [/security]
TOP/static... 
----
I've been able to get login and registration to work... but now after login I can't render index.html get error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`... on view handler for  @app.route('/') --- return render_template('index.html')

Comment: We have determined that the app works when running on local system... but does not work when accessed from remote browser.... are there any ways to test request from local and remote servers?

Comment: Solved.   The issue was in the /etc/hosts had 127.0.1.1 for the server hostname.  By changing this to NIC ip address this solved the problem. 
Clearly FlaskBootstrapSecurity is more secure than any other Flask app sample I have seen -- still trying to learn how to build an integrated solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the /etc/hosts had 127.0.1.1 for the server hostname. By changing this to NIC ip address this solved the problem.